# Sending data through php page from android form

Tags: php, android

I am helping one of my friend in his android app assignment. Here is the problem statement given in his android assignment.

Statement:- There should be proper implementation of POST method with queue to accommodate the data request even when device is in offline mode and execute data sync request from queue as soon as device is online again.

How this task could be done. Correct me if I am wrong, I am thinking that this requires to be done using SyncAdapter. If I am correct and if it has any other way then suggest the same with a tutorial link for implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, indeed you need to use `SyncAdapter`. Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html).

Logically, you need to have a message queue, where you push new messages based on user events and possibly other events as well and you need to pop the messages from there and pass to `SyncAdapter`.

Comment: So can you tell me the flow of doing the same as I am confused, from where I should start.

Comment: @Raj, you should take a look at a few tutorials, they will help you to become able to determine where to start. This is a pretty good article, for instance: devcenter.kinvey.com/android/guides/caching-offline